# Running Python threads concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, process, multiprocessing

I have two functions I want to run concurrently, as I want to keep sending and receiving messages in my socket. This is my main function, but I can't get the threads to run concurrently. Only sending is running. How can I fix this?

```
def __init__(self):
    d = {}
    d["id"] = "MyId"
    d["Count"] = 0
    d["Message"] = "Just a little message for you"
    self.d = d

    restart = False
    self.restart = self

def sendMessage(self):
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer((DEFAULT_IP, HOST_PORT), MyMessageHandler)
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        sendData = json.dumps(self.d, ensure_ascii=False)
        server.socket.sendto(sendData, (DEFAULT_IP, SENDING_PORT))
        self.restart = True

def receiveMessages(self):
    #I know there isn't a message being received. The count is an example of me
    #'receiving' data and then sending it out
    msg_count = 0
    while True:
        if self.restart == True:
            msg_count = 0
            self.d["Count"] = 0
            self.restart = False
        else:
            msg_count += 1
            self.d["Count"] = msg_count
def main(self):
    receiving = threading.Thread(target=self.receiveMessages)
    sending = threading.Thread(target=self.sendMessage(self.d))
    receiving.start()
    sending.start()

    receiving.join()
    sending.join()
```

Comment: can you share the code running in the two threads?

Comment: Multiproccessing wouldn't be useful for you?

Comment: @srfrnk I added the code to the question

Comment: @Mikael No because I need to receive data and then send data based on those messages. Currently, I don't have actually receiving messages and rather just a loop for a count as a test. Multiple processes don't share data between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `sending = threading.Thread(target=self.sendMessage(self.d))` is actually calling the function `sendMessages`.
This function is blocking and will never return thus the code will never reach `receiving.start()` and the receiving thread will never run.

Change to `sending = threading.Thread(target=self.sendMessage)` and all will start working.

Comment: Thank you! That was definitely a mistake on my part because I didn't add the parentheses for the first thread.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Only sending is running. How can I fix this?

Your `sendMessage(self.d)` is only executed **once** as you pass the  result of the `method sendMessage(self.d)` to the `target` parameter.
Change to

```
sending = threading.Thread(target=self.sendMessage)
```